# Can't override !important rule at wordpress "One take template"

Tags: html, css

There is a !important rule on my template that was inserted by the developer himself, and it doesn't matter what I do, I won't be able to override it. I'm trying to style a single element in the site's top menu, at http://akecheta.com
I can do it with the console, it works on client side, so I update my custom.css code and when I reload the page, nothing actually changed.

This is my code:

```
<li id="menu-item-1590" class="bp-menu bp-login-nav menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1591"><a href="http://akecheta.com/wp-login.php?action=login&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fakecheta.com%2Fmembers%2Fadministrador%2F&amp;_wpnonce=6e8d66da25"><span>Log Out</span></a></li>
```

The css rule annoying me is:

```
.site-nav > ul li a {
  color: #000000 !important;
}
```

I've tried overriding it like this:

```
 .site-nav.bp-menu.bp-login-nav > ul > li + li {
color: #ff000 !important;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

This

```
.bp-menu.bp-login-nav a {
  color: rgb(249, 24, 24) !important;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

this

```
li#menu-item-1590 a {
      color: rgb(249, 24, 24) !important;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

this

```
li#menu-item-1590.bp-menu.bp-login-nav a {
          color: rgb(249, 24, 24) !important;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
```

And this

```
li#menu-item-1590.site-nav > ul li a {
      color: #000000 !important;
    }
```

Where .bp-menu and .bp-login-nav are two classes used by a plugin that has a link in the menu. I suspect there is also javascript involved, but I don't know where.

UPTADE

It is #menu-item-1590, not #menu-item-1591
And is .bp-login-nav not .bp-logout-nav

The previous ones are for loggedin users only. Sorry.

Comment: Is your custom.css loaded after the default css file?

Comment: And if it's a single element are you able to put in an inline style? `<a style="color: #ff000;" href=""></a>`

Comment: If you by inline you're talking about editing the HTML, I can't, changes gets lost during system updates.

Comment: I see now it's wordpress, remember to clear cache (if you use a caching plugin) when checking for changes. Logged in as an admin it shouldn't matter but if you're using something like cloudflare, they will have a cache of their own of your css files.

Comment: I've already disabled the cache plugin. Good observation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bp-menu.bp-logout-nav a {color:#ff0000;}` Should do the job

About not being able to override `.site-nav > ul li a` that's because it's being implemented on your header before your **style.css** by the file named **theme-setup.php**.

In order to remove the `!important` from:

```
.site-nav > ul li a {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

You'll need to go to: **onetake > includes > theme-setup.php**

Around line 72 on **theme-setup.php** you'll find something like this, which is what's generating the `!important` on `.site-nav > ul li a`

```
$onetake_custom_css  .=  '.site-nav > ul  li a{color:'.esc_attr($nav_menu_color).' !important;}';
```

Just remove the `!important` from it, and then you'll be able to add new styling for your links normally, or by using `!important` as well. Here's how the code above should look like after removing the `!important`

```
$onetake_custom_css  .=  '.site-nav > ul  li a{color:'.esc_attr($nav_menu_color).' ;}';
```

Comment: You're telling me to hack the code? I can't because if I do so, I'll lose the changes after the theme's update. It has to be done in the custom.css file. Or at least with javascript, but js is for last case. :/

Comment: Also, that's for a single element, if I remove it, I'll screw the whole menu links.

Comment: What? You are just changing the color value from this: `.site-nav > ul li a {color: #000000 !important;}` to this : `.site-nav > ul li a {color: #ff0000 !important;}`. how is that going to affect your update functionalities? Plus, when you update a theme all files are overwritten even these you are trying to change, **style.css** or **head.php**. You're not gonna loose the possibility of update the theme in the future for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS to this instead:

```
.bp-logout-nav a {
  color: #ff0000 !important;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```